# I have problem with Gradle sync with Kotlin Android Studio 4

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I When doing sync, I get this error

**Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.72/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.72.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
**

Gradle 6.5
Android Studio 4.1.2
JDK 14.0.2

Update : "I Downloaded This File kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.72.pom But I dont know where i can save it ?"

Comment: Could you please post your gradle files and also the error screenshot for us to review further.

Comment: please update your kotlin version to 1.4.21

Answer (score 0):

try updating your kotlin version to

> 1.4.21